# Anyone with the link can view images in Google Drive when deploy as a web app by apps script doesn't show in web browser in IOS

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, google-apps-script, web-applications

I created an apps script web app and I used some images from my google drive that already shared publicly (Anyone with the link can view). In my html tag, I put an image URL like this

> `<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=***some file ID here***&export=download">`.

In about 3-4 months ago, it worked well when it show those image in chrome browser in both Android and IOS. Now, it only show images in Android but it doesn't in IOS.

How to fix that. I really appreciate for some advice.

Comment: Provide iOS browser console logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can always host the images on an image host service if anyone with the link can view it anyway. I use imgbb.com and it works with all browsers as well as android and iPhone as far as I'm aware.

You'll just have to upload images to the hosting service and get the src url's from there which may be an extra step you don't want to take.